# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cordova, slim

I am using angular.js to make a ReSTful app for mobile devices using cordova.
for server side I am using slim framework.all according to this tutorial:(http://www.angularcode.com/user-authentication-using-angularjs-php-mysql/)

But when i uploaded api folder to server, error occurs :
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I have read about adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
and implemented it according to this link : 
http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/810-no-subject

```
$app->get('/session', function() {
    **$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');**  
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $session = $db->getSession();
    $response["uid"] = $session['uid'];
    $response["email"] = $session['email'];
    $response["name"] = $session['name'];
    echoResponse(200, $session);
});
```

also tried

```
$app->get('/session', function() {
    **$session->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');**  
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $session = $db->getSession();
    $response["uid"] = $session['uid'];
    $response["email"] = $session['email'];
    $response["name"] = $session['name'];
    echoResponse(200, $session);
});
```

I am still receiving the same error.

--> Also is the last line correct ? `echoResponse(200, $session);`

Thank You in advance :)

### update

I am using same file on  firefox and chrome and chrome is able to access the file on server. 
Also one JSON file on my server was being accessed by cordova app earlier and now is not working. The calling code is exactly same ie

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(product_data) {
    $scope.artists = product_data;
  });
}])
```

Comment: do some more reading...there's more to it than one header, need to account for preflight requests also

Comment: Good start is to write the header to actual response. You are now trying to write it into undefined variable. Use $app->response->header(...) instead.

Comment: @MikaTuupola You mean changing(to $app->response) only for that line or everywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag. This will prevent that from showing up and allow you to develop on your desktop.

Cordova / PhoneGap basically do this for you when it's in app form. You may need to have a look around to see how to open it with the flag depending on which operating system you're on.

Also, **do not continue to use your browser for normal activities with the flag enabled**. If possible, also use the CLI to open a new user profile so it doesn't affect your existing profile and open you up to any security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Why would you suggest doing this instead of implementing CORS? It's a server side issue so phones will have the same problem.

Comment: This is what i do when trying my app on local server but the problem is from the server as the permission is not granted.

Comment: @Cerad This is how I solved the issue on a cordova app I've recently been working on, the difference was I was working with a third-party API. But hey, if it works, not a problem. Seems in this case, it doesn't work though unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Some web browsers disallow CORS from localhost (or any alias for localhost such as 127.0.0.1). The solution is to access it using non-localhost url.

One such url that may work is your IP address.

If you prefer not to use your IP address (maybe because it's assigned randomly by your router each time you connect) then you can assign a fake domain to yourself by modifying `/etc/hosts` (or `Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows).

For example, add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1   thismachine
```

Then you can access your web server by typing `http://thismachine` in your web browser.

Comment: Which of the above two codes is correct and also which variable should be   placed in the last line

Comment: There is only one code. The second is what you type in your browser

Comment: Also, which line you define your domain doesn't matter. I prefer to put it at the top of the file. Some prefer to put it at the last line. Just make sure the file ends in a newline in case some software refuse to process the last line if it doesn't have  a newline - it's the reason I prefer to put it at the top.