# WebSockets from Vue component to flask - can't connect to server

Tags: vue.js, flask, websocket, socket.io

I am making my first steps with websockets in my application. 
My frontend is using vue.js while my backend uses flask.

In my component I wrote this.

```
  created() {
    console.log('Starting connection to WebSocket Server');
    // this.connection = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
    this.connection = new WebSocket('wss://192.168.0.22:5000');

    this.connection.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event);
    };

    this.connection.onopen = function (event) {
      console.log(event);
      console.log('Successfully connected to the echo websocket server...');
    };
  },
```

In my flask app.py besides other stuff I have this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
CORS(app)

"""Socket.IO decorator to create a websocket event handler"""
@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)


def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

**In my browser I get the error that firefox could not make a connection to wss://192.168.0.22:5050.** I already tried the frontend with the websocket from a tutorial which is commented out now.
I am not sure, which url I should use for my own backend or what I have to add there.
Sorry if this is obvious but I am a complete beginnern.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
In chrome the error I receive is "WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.0.38:5000/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out" 
Also as I saw this error when trying out stuff, maybe this question could be relevant? [vue socket.io connection attempt returning "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" error even when origins have been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376277/vue-socket-io-connection-attempt-returning-no-access-control-allow-origin-hea)

Comment: I am not very familliar to flask but I suppose its dev server does not run on a secure connection. so try to connect to ws:// instead of wss://

Comment: thank you. I tried it but unfortunately i still get the same error just with ws://

Comment: I think you are not initiatializing the socketio. instead of `app.run()` try `socketio.run(app)`

Comment: oh yes, I indeed should do that. I improved it. 
Also I think i used the wrong port. 5000 is the one flask is running on, not 5050. However still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the part for the socket which i ended up using for the client/component:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

created() {
    // test websocket connection
    const socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.38:5000');

    // getting data from server
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    socket.on('connect', function () {
      console.error('connected to webSocket');
      //sending to server
      socket.emit('my event', { data: 'I\'m connected!' });
    });

    // we have to use the arrow function to bind this in the function
    // so that we can access Vue  & its methods
    socket.on('update_on_layouts', (data) => {
      this.getAllLayouts();
      console.log(data);
    });
  },
```

The Flask server code stayed as shown above. Additionally here is an example from my flask server to emit the update_on_layouts `socketio.emit('update_on_layouts', 'success')`